# When changed locale app change type digits format of device

Tags: android, android-context, android-date

I am changing locale language app like bellow:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    String languageID = new SessionManager(newBase).getIdLanguage();
    super.attachBaseContext(ContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, languageID));
}
```

**Problem:** But when I change locale language app, digit of app is changed.

But I need to don't change `digits`.(I need to digits english)

And my `ContextWrapper.class` is bellow:

```
public class ContextWrapper extends android.content.ContextWrapper {

    private ContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static android.content.ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (language != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(language)) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
            } else {
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        } else {
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
            } else {
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }
        return new ContextWrapper(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

What can I do?

How can I set `digits` default of app on `en` ?

For example when I set locale language to `Arabic` get me digit base arabic digits or get me Date base arabic digits.

I need to resolve this problem in all of app I don't need to use from bellow way:

```
int i = 1;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
nf.format(i);
```

And I test from bellow way but don't work:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar", "EN");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similr issue with date
here is how I fixed it hope it will help you

```
Calendar mydate = Calendar.getInstance();
        mydate.setTimeInMillis(unix * 1000);
        return
                String.format(Locale.US, "%02d", mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                        + "." +
                        String.format(Locale.US, "%02d", (mydate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1))
                        + "." + mydate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: did you mean the date in the status-bar change or the date inside your app ?

Comment: OK. then just use String.format(Locale.US, ...)  and reformat your date before assigning the value to TextView. pot your date code if u want so I can point it for you.